# Hot to access google map object to get LatLngToPoint

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use the `fromLatLngToPoint` from the Google Maps API. From examples i know it should be done in this way:

`var pro= map.getProjection();
      var wc = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(loc);`

but I fail at accessing the map object already. After googling and trying for hours I need some help from the pros.

Here is the Fiddle:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delcon/c2q7kLk5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `getProjection()` isn't available until the map is finished initializing. You have to wait on the `"projection_changed"` event before accessing it.

As I know your code should looks like this:

```
var map, pro;
var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961);
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: loc,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scroll: {
            x: 0,
            y: $(window).scrollTop()
        },
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: map.getCenter()
    });
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,"projection_changed", function() {
       $(console).text(map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(loc).toString());
        console.log(map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(loc).toString());
     });

} //end function
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

this is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2q7kLk5/6/)

Comment: @Delcon if this question helps you could you please votes up it?